# Stack Level Too Deep for Merge Sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm practicing Merge Sort in Ruby and am running into an error where my Stack Level is too Deep. Here is the code:

```
def sort(numbers)

    num_length = numbers.length
    if num_length <= 1
        numbers
    end

    half_of_elements = (num_length / 2).round

    left = numbers.take(half_of_elements)
    right = numbers.drop(half_of_elements)

    sorted_left = sort(left)
    sorted_right = sort(right)

    print sorted_left, sorted_right
    #merge(sorted_left, sorted_right)
end
```

I've commented out the merge method because I just want to see the sorted arrays, but my code keeps getting stuck and I get the error. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You failed to `return numbers` in your guard condition.  So it just skips past that and calls itself recursively with the same argument.

When you get a stack level too deep on a recursive call that usually means you have a recursive case that winds up making the same call.  I debug those by adding a print at the start of the recursive call.  Once I see the call that is leading to calling itself, I walk through what happens for that case very carefully.